# Get table row value based on button click using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to get the table row value from onclick event. Below the table, I am using

```
Group name|Manage group

Test 1    | Button

Test 2    | Button
```

If I click 'Button' from the table row, I need to get the respective group name value from the table row.

Below the script, I am trying. But it is printing only the first group name value "Test 1" for both buttons.

```
var table = document.getElementById("user_table");
       var rows = table.rows;
       for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
           rows[i].onclick = (function (e) {
               var rowid = (this.cells[0].innerHTML);
               var j = 0;
               var td = e.target;
               while( (td = td.previousElementSibling) != null ) 
                   j++;
               alert(rows[1].cells[j].innerHTML);
           });
       }
```

alert(rows[1].cells[j].innerHTML) printing  group name value Test 1 and if I click second row button it is showing Test 1 only.But I need to get Test 2 if I click second row button.

Html file

```
<table id="user_table"  style='overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll;width:100%;height:auto' class="table table-bordered" >
 <thead>
 <tr class="info">
   <th>Group Name</th>
   <th>User Group</th>

 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="table_body">
 <br>
 
   <% @array.each do |user| %>
   <tr>
   
     <td >
       <%=user['group_name']%>
     </td>
       <td>
         <button id='manageusrbtn' name="button" type="button" class="editbtn" onclick="manageUserGroups()" style="background-color: #008CBA; color: white; border-radius: 6px;" >Manage User Groups</button>
       </td>
        
     <% end %>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: `alert(rows[1]....` you appear to have hardcoded your test alert to row 1

Comment: yes.How to get value from other table rows.I tried adding i instead of hardcoded value.But it is not working

Comment: Without html and tagged [jquery], I'd give the td you want a class and do `$(this).find("td.groupname").text()` but looking at your code, looks like it should be just `alert(rowid)`

Comment: added my html as well

Comment: Adding the event to your *button* makes the most sense, but from your code `alert(rowid)` does what you've asked for  https://jsfiddle.net/1tw7jqp9/1/

Comment: thanks.This is also working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to attach the click event handler to the button and not to each cell.
For this you can use:

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

The snippet:

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll('#user_table tr button');
table.forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var rowid = (this.closest('td').previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
        console.log(rowid);
    })
});
```

```html
<table id="user_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Group name</th>
        <th>Manage group</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td><button>Button</button></td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td><button>Button</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```